# Is $\mathbb{Q}^{2}\cup \mathbb{I}^{2} $ connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

It is well-known that $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{I}^{2}$ (where $\mathbb I = \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$) are disconnected spaces with the usual topology from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but how about the union? I figure it is, but I couldn't solved it. I've tried to express the set as the union of connected sets with nonempty intersection, because I think that is the key; but I reached nowhere.

Comment: Presumably $Q$ is the rationals and $I$ the irrationals?

Comment: Maybe consider the lines $y=\pm x+q$ where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$? These lines are connected and contain all of $\mathbb{Q}^2$, so you can take the relative closure inside your set.

Comment: Q are the rationals, I the irrationals, sorry.

Comment: Denote $X=\mathbb{Q}^2\cup(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})^2$. Let $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ be continuous. **Observation 1:** If $(x,y)\in X$, then there is a real number $r>0$ such that on $((x-r,x+r)\times(y-r,y+r))\cap X$ the function $f$ takes the same value as at $(x,y)$.

**Observation 2:** If $(x,y)\in X$ and $r$ is a real number, then for any fixed choice of $s,t$ integers, at least one of $(x+(-1)^sr,y),(x,y+(-1)^tr)$ or $(x+(-1)^2r,y+(-1)^tr)$ is in $X$. Assume that $f$ is surjective. Then starting from two points $p_1,p_2$ where $f$ takes different values, use the two observations ...

Comment: ... to construct two convergent sequences of points of $X$ that converge to the same limit and such that on one $f$ takes the value $0$ and in the other the value $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are two points in $Q^2 \cup I^2$ with $a \ne c$ and $b \ne d$.
Then I claim there is a curve of the form $(x, f(x))$ for $x \in [\min(a,c), \max(a,c)]$
where $f$ is a continuous monotone function such that $f(a) = b$, $f(c)=d$, and $f(x)$ rational if and only if $x$ is rational. 
If so, $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are in the same connected component of $Q^2 \cup I^2$.

For simplicity, consider the case where $a < c$ and $b < d$.  If $m = (d-b)/(c-a)$ is the slope of the line segment joining $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$, you can construct $f$ so that 
all secant lines $(r,f(r))$ to $(s,f(s))$ where either $r=a$ or $r$ is rational or $f(r)$ is rational, and
either $s=b$ or $s$ is rational or $f(s)$ is rational, have slope strictly between $m/2$ and $2m$.  The curve is constructed by an inductive procedure using enumerations of
the rationals in $(a,c)$ and the rationals in $(b,d)$. At each stage, we will have a 
piecewise-linear curve from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$.  We take either the next rational $r$ in $(a,c)$ or the next rational $s$ in $(b,d)$: if the point on the curve corresponding to $x=r$ or $y=s$ is not in $Q^2$, we move it slightly in the vertical or horizontal direction (respectively) so that it is in $Q^2$, but the slopes of the modified piecewise-linear curve are still all strictly between $m/2$ and $2m$.
Then it is easy to show that the limit of these piecewise-linear curves exists and is a continuous curve $(x,f(x))$ such that $x$ is rational if and only if $f(x)$ is rational.

Comment: So, you are affirming that there is some connected set which contains these two points. I don't understand the construction process very well... you are defining a piecewise function that joins each point, say $ (x_{n-1}, y_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{Q}^{2}$ with ($x_{n},y_{n})  \in \mathbb{Q}^{2} $?
However, it would't be in each piece of line elements that are not in the set $ \mathbb {Q}^{2}\cup\mathbb{I}^{2} $? In such case that line would no longer be connected in the set. Also, what would happen if a = c, or b = d?

Comment: By construction, for each rational $r \in (a,c)$ there is a rational $s \in (b,d)$ such that $(r, s)$ is one of the vertices of one of the piecewise-linear curves, 
and therefore of all subsequent ones.  Similarly for each rational $s \in (b,d)$ there is a rational $r \in (a,c)$ such that $(r,s)$ is one of the vertices. 
The limit of the piecewise-linear curves is a continuous curve $y = f(x)$; since the slopes of the piecewise-linear curves are all between $m/2$ and $2m$, $f$ is one-to-one with $m/2 \le (f(x_1) - f(x_2))/(x_1 - x_2) \le 2 m$ for all $x_1 \ne x_2$.

Comment: If $x$ is rational, $f(x)$ is rational and if $f(x)$ is rational, $x$ must be rational. So if $x$ is irrational, $f(x)$ must also be irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying the same idea as Robert Israel. Take families of rationals $p_n,q_n$ ($n\in\mathbb Z$) such that: $p_n<p_{n+1}$; $q_n\ne q_{n+1}$; $p_n\to a$ and $q_n\to b$ as $n\to-\infty$; and  $p_n\to c$ and $q_n\to d$ as $n\to\infty$. Take segment of every $(p_n,q_n)$ to $(p_{n+1},q_{n+1})$. The union of all of these segments, together with the points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, is the graph of a continuous function $f:[a,c]\to\mathbb R$ satisfying what Robert Israel asserts.